# string with special characters conversion

Tags: c#, string, special-characters, string-conversion

I know it's a very silly problem as I'm still newbie.

**Case :**
String A : An output string from an encryption algorithm ( contains special characters )
String B : An output string from a hash function of String A ( contains special characters )

```
String C = A + "|" + B;
```

**Problem :**
I want to send them together from sender as String C so that I can Separate them in receiver
But String A & B may contains my separator "|"

So what do you suggest for me ?  [ C# ]

Comment: why can't you pass them as two separate parameters?

Comment: Does `B` have constant length?

Comment: or why can't you use separator, which your encryption algorithm will never produce ?

Comment: Use a character that can't be produced by the outputs you are using.

Comment: @BrokenGlass Because I may send as strings as I need

Comment: @zerkms No It's variable length string

Comment: @Umar It's using all charactes as I treats Strings as bytes and play with them ( El GAMAL Algorithm ) then when I convert them to string it produce a dummy random special characters

Comment: @Ahmed Ghoneim: which hashing algorithm has variable length result?

Comment: @zerkms ElGamal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme

Comment: @Ahmed Ghoneim: Never treat strings as bytes or bytes as strings.  Always use some encoding to convert from one to the other.

Comment: @Ahmed Ghoneim: it is not a hash function, is it?

Comment: @zerkms What I know about hash is that it can't be reversed, sorry I'm new to whole of security things :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to convert the output from the encryption tool (which hopefully returns raw bytes) into something like Base64 using the Convert.ToBase64String function, which should be safe to use "|" with. You lose out on space efficiency though, since Base64 wastes a good amount of space, but if you're dealing with small data you'd be ok.

If your encryption code does/can not return bytes, you'd have to convert it to bytes first using the appropriate encoder, i.e. Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() if your string is in ASCII encoding.

```
//On the sender side
byte[] bytesA = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(A);
byte[] bytesB = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(B);
string encA = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesA);
string encB = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesB);

string C = encA + "|" + encB;

//On the receiver side
string[] parts = C.Split('|');
string A = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(parts[0]));
string B = Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(parts[1]));
```

Comment: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters.

Comment: public static byte [ ] StringToByteArray ( string _String )
        {
            return Encoding . Default . GetBytes ( _String );
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString ( byte [ ] _ByteArray )
        {
            return Encoding . Default . GetString ( _ByteArray );

        }

Comment: public static string Base64Encode ( string data )
        {
            return Convert . ToBase64String ( StringToByteArray ( data ) );
        }

        public static string Base64Decode ( string data )
        {
            return ByteArrayToString ( Convert . FromBase64String ( data ) );
        }

Comment: When you are decoding did you remember to split the string back into parts A and B?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're missing, but I'll modify my answer with code for your case.

Answer (score 3):

You could enode the length of the first string in the first 3 characters. Then you use the length at the receiver to split the strings.

Not pretty, but works.

Comment: this could possibly be the most efficient solution, depending on the length of the strings, and how many characters would have to be replaced in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could escape all pipes in string C

e.g.

- define "=" as an escape character (you could use "\", which would be typical, but that will really mess with you since it's also an escape character for strings in c#)
- replace all "=" in strings A and B with "=E" (E for Equals)
- replace all "|" in strings A and B with "=P" (P for pipe)
- join them together with the pipe

that will guarantee that you have no pipes in your string except the one joining A and B, but it will also let you split them on the other side and restore all existing pipes to their original places.  Just reverse the order of operations.

Comment: note that the inefficiency would be limited to +1 characters for each "=" and "|" in your strings

Comment: What should he do if encryption algorithm produce |= in output ? It will be replaced on other side as |. And it's incorrect

Comment: you are correct, I mis-typed when I created my response...Edited it to fix problem.